# Utilizar módulos e suas dependências de uma library no angular 9

Tags: angular, library

Estou criando uma **library** com **angular 9** para ser utilizada em vários projetos e gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar dependências dentro de um módulo sem precisar importa-las na aplicação principal (a que utiliza a library):

Por exemplo:
Criei o módulo `MaterialModule` dentro da minha library

```
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

No módulo da aplicação principal, importaria `MaterialModule` em `screen1.modules.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Screen1Component } from './screen1.component';
import { MaterialModule } from 'componentes-web/lib/shared/material-module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MaterialModule],
  declarations: [Screen1Component],
  exports: [Screen1Component]
})
export class Screen1Module {}
```

Utilizando a tag

```
<mat-card>
```

do angular material no html em `screen1.component.html`:

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{'titulo.card' | translate}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{'sub-titulo.card' | translate}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>

  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">{{'btn.novo' | translate}}</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Ou seja, utilizar a tag

```
<mat-card>
```

sem a necessidade de importar `MatCardModule` no meu módulo `Screen1Module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Screen1Component } from './screen1.component';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatCardModule],
  declarations: [Screen1Component],
  exports: [Screen1Component]
})
export class Screen1Module {}
```

Em minha library, estou exportando o módulo `MaterialModule`:

```
export * from './lib/componentes-web.component';
export * from './lib/componentes-web.module';
export * from './lib/componentes-web.service';

//material modulo
export * from './lib/shared/material-module';
```

Mas meu arquivo `material-module.d.ts` tem somente:

```
export declare class MaterialModule {
}
```

Comment: Não é que não tenha como, mas parece causar mais problemas do que resolver, ao meu ver, faz mais ter um template desse arquivo e colar nos seus projetos. Assim você consegue a facilidade, mas mantém a versatilidade de cada projeto importar os seus módulos

Comment: qual o problema que ta dando?

Comment: Diz que `MaterialModule` não tem `@NgModule` com os imports....no geral, queria utilizar nos meus projetos principais, os módulos do angular material só importando `MaterialModule` e esse me daria acesso aos módulos do angular material tipo por extensão